# Regular Expression to fail Team City build

Tags: regex, expression, teamcity

I'm using Team City to trigger a script that does some performance testing and generates an output in this format: **"Publisher 0, Rate:  45600 /s"**. The only thing that changes in the output is the rate number (in this example, 45600).

Basically, I need to fail the build in case my rate is under 50000. I'm using Team City Failure Conditions (regex), however I'm struggling to find a regular expression that would identify if this number is < 50000.

This is what I got so far:
**^[0-4][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$|^50000$** ---> this would identify any number in the logs where the rate number is < 50000, however there are heaps of logs data, then it would identify other numbers that I'm not interested, so this doesn't do what I need. Another downside is that this regex doesn't capture numbers that have something else (strings) before it, so it doesn't even identify the number in the format I want ----> "Publisher 0, Rate:  45600 /s"

Another attempt was using this regex: **Rate:\s+\K\S+**
It only matches the number after "Rate" which is exactly what I want! However, I couldn't find a way to match the number **only when number is < 50000**
Also, Team City doesn't allow the use of "\K", so I need to find a different solution.

Here are a few log entries that I'm using for regex testing purposes:

- Publisher 0, Rate:  45600 /s
- Publisher 0, Rate:  50001 /s
- 10
- 100
- 1000
- 10000
- 50001
- 100000

ps: in this case, a successful regex for me would be the one that only matches "45600".

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers!

Comment: What if you combine both? `Rate:\s+[0-4]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]$`

Comment: @
user2253130: Try this one: `/\s+((?:[0,4]\d{0,4}|\d{1,4})\b)/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/8HFJNZ/2

You can make the regex more specific by adding the `Rate:` and `/s`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help/suggestions. Here is the final regex that worked for me (I also tested in Team City, all good)

```
Rate:\s+[0-4]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]\s
```

Cheers.